# problem with masterpage and jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, jquery, master-pages

I have a MasterPage that inside its content section I added a FORM element.
When accessing that page, all my controls are renamed since the FORM is runat=server.
And thus when selecting in jquery, even the form has been renamed

How can I fix that?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a master page, all elements will have ct100__etc appended to the ID of the element.  This is a feature since its a naming container.  Typically, the way to work around it is to use syntax like:

```
$("#<%= button.ClientID %>").click(..);
```

To access the longer ID's, or rely on CSS classes to identify elements.  Another trick is to wrap certain sections of the form with a DIV HTML element and give it an ID to target.

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, that's the behavior of .Net. What you can do is adjust your jquery usage to incorporate the ClientID of the controls you're using. The easiest way is to have some sort of translation variable injected into script in the head somewhere.

```
<script language="javascript">
    var myControl1 = '<%=myControl1.ClientID %>';
</script>
```

Then you can use myControl1 as a string variable to inject the client id into your jquery calls in a more readable fashion.

Comment: Before that I have FORM wrapping the content section and inside another FORM and it made no problems whatsoever

Comment: @oshafran - I don't really understand what you're saying in your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this post here

http://john-sheehan.com/blog/custom-jquery-selector-for-aspnet-webforms/

Explains it all pretty clearly. the trick is to use ClientId

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the `.ClientID` approach suggested in many of the other answers, you can use jQuery's [endswith](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) selector.

eg: Select the element whose id endswith "myid" (eg ctl001_form1_myid)

```
$('[id$="myid"]');
```

or if you are using .net 4, you can set `ClientIdMode="false"` to prevent the renaming.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`Control.ClientID`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx) for this. Something like

```
$("#<%= yourelement.ClientID %>")
```

Comment: I dont want it to rename my objects

Comment: You cannot do this. Its a default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a CSSCLASS and then access by $('.classname')

```
<asp:TextBox id="tb4" Text="Hello World!" cssclass="txtboxtb4" runat="server" />


alert($('.txtboxtb4').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is put controls in span tag.

```
<span id="txt">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</span>
```

Than you can select you element like this in jQuery.

```
$('#txt > input').val('Hello world');
```

But my way is, select element with ends with selector.

```
$('input[id$="txt"]').val('Hello world');
```

Works for my cases. Hope help.